# Form with webbrowser minimized when form.show is used VB net

Tags: vb.net, forms, browser

here is what my issue is, i am using form1 (me) to with a webbrowser to show custom errors, i check an INI file to see what screen i need and i do a navagate.webbrowser1 and the web address, i then show the form with the webbrowser taking up the whole form.  when i run this, i get a black screen or a white screen, or no form set in the front I call a program that installs a printer in the background during this process.

i want the form to be in the front while the other program runs and fisnishes, this is the end of my program, and this has some animations on the webpage that shows the user the program is still running, but i can't get the form to show up.

here is my code:

```
        '*********************************************************************************************
        'this set the correct screen for Exit
        '*********************************************************************************************
        RBoot = reboot1
        If RBoot = "True" Then

            closeweb = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/_report/enrollment.asp?page=completesuccess"
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://XXXXXXXXXXXX/_report/enrollment.asp?page=completesuccess")
            var1 = 0
            Form9.Hide()
            Form10.Hide()
            Do Until var1 = 5
                Me.Show()
                Me.Refresh()
                Thread.Sleep(400)
            Loop


        ElseIf RBoot = "False" Then

            closeweb = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/_report/enrollment.asp?page=completenoreboot&name=" & computername
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/_report/enrollment.asp?page=completenoreboot&name=" & computername)
            var1 = 0
            Form9.Hide()
            Form10.Hide()
            Do Until var1 = 5
                Me.Show()
                Me.Refresh()
                Thread.Sleep(400)
            Loop


        End If


        '*********************************************************************************************
        ' this runs the Printer Installer
        '*********************************************************************************************
        Dim Compini As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\temp\computerinfo.ini")
        logg = "Computer Info INI:" & vbCrLf & Compini
        Call logging()

        If Compini.Contains("Printer") Then

            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(current_DIR & "\ Printer Installer\Printerinstaller.exe") Then
                Me.Show()
             Dim printerinstall As New Process
                printerinstall.StartInfo.FileName = current_DIR & "\Printer Installer\PrinterInstaller.exe"
                printerinstall.StartInfo.Arguments = " -D C"
                printerinstall.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                printerinstall.Start()
                Try
                    While printerinstall.HasExited = False
                        Thread.Sleep(200)
                        Me.Show()
                    End While
                Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
                End Try
                logg = "Ran " & current_DIR & "\Printer Installer\PrinterInstaller.exe"
                Call logging()
            Else
                logg = "Can't Find " & current_DIR & "\Printer Installer\PrinterInstaller.exe"
                Call logging()
                WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/_report/enrollment.asp?page=printerinstallernotfound&name=" & computername)
                Form9.Hide()
                Form10.Hide()
                Me.Show()
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            logg = "No Printer Selected and Printer Installer didn't run"
            Call logging()
        End If
```

Comment: There's only so far you can get with trial and error programming.  You've hit the wall solidly with this code, every line of code is broken in one way or another.  Pick up a book or attend a school to get ahead.  And get rid of the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the form stay in front with:

```
Form1.TopMost = True
```

And you can minimize the form:

```
Form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
```

(change `Form1` to `Me` if you are refering on the same form)

Answer (score 0):

Why is the "closeweb" variable in there? It doesn't seem to serve a purpose

Are you re-using 'reboot1' elsewhere? If not, why change variable names at the top?

Consider not hiding form9 and form10 - are you sure those don't contain the content you are meaning to display?

Remove the loops, the code is unnecessary - there are far better ways to accomplish what you are trying to do there. Try to just show your 'me' form there without the loop and see what happens (don't refresh)

At the printer installation process, you are hiding and showing forms again. You should give them names so you can better track what you are doing. It seems all this hiding and showing is causing the black/white screen.